# MKMapView iOS6 - buggy and slow on scroll and zoom

Tags: performance, ipad, ios6, mkmapview

with the iOS5 MKMapView (google maps) i could zoom and scroll fine on any device.
Now with iOS6 MKMapView (apple maps) when I start scrolling around the app ends up hanging pretty much every time. 
This worked fine under iOS5

issues
- new memory footprint of apple maps is 15x compared to google maps
- MKMapView becomes unresponsive on my ipad2 in full screen if you scroll around enough ( 20 seconds)
- annotations start jumping around as well as it begins to become unresponsive

Has anyone got a nice working example on ipad2 with a full screen MKMapView that lets you scroll and zoom without crashing?

Thanks

Comment: How does the official map app react?

Comment: It becomes very laggy and ends up freezing as you scroll around even without zooming. It might be something to do with it being embedded inside a cocos2d app. But as I say the old google map worked fine in iOS5. I see facebook uses BING maps for it embedded map, maybe this is a better way to go.

Comment: The official map app isn't embedded in a cocos2d app. I mean the Maps app that Apple wrote. If that is slow and laggy too, it means your device can't handle iOS 6 maps, if it runs fine, then it's a problem with your app.